# Como colocar um limite ao meu vetor?

Tags: python-3.x, array, numpy

Estou fazendo um trabalho, e nele encontro um vetor com possíveis valores para uma variável, entretanto, os valores que realmente atendem a resposta, estão contidos na restrição `1.5 < R < 2` . Como eu transformaria o vetor `R` completo no vetor `R` real que atende a restrição? ou seja, aquele que a casa `0` começa com o valor `1.5`.

Ex: `1.5 < V < 2` , sendo que `V` é um vetor decrescente com 7 mil casas.

Segue o que tentei fazer:

```
   
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parametros Físicos:
m = 0.558 # massa (kg)

# Parâmetros Modais:
zeta = np.arange(0.000001,(np.sqrt(1/2)-0.001),0.0001) # fator amortecimento 

# Força externa aplicada:
F0 = 200 # amplitude da força (N)

rpico = np.sqrt(1-2*zeta**2)

ZY = (rpico**2)/((1-rpico**2)**2 + (2*zeta*rpico)**2)**(1/2)
i = j = 0
while i < 7061:
    i = i + 1
    if ZY[i]>1.5 and ZY[i]<2:
        zyl[j] = ZY[i]
        j = j+1 
        
        
plt.figure()
plt.plot(zeta,rpico)
plt.xlabel('Zeta')
plt.ylabel('rpico')
plt.title('-')
plt.grid (True)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(rpico,zyl)
plt.xlabel('rpico')
plt.ylabel('ZY')
plt.title('-')
plt.grid (True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz a seguinte alteração no código:

```
ZY = (rpico**2)/((1-rpico**2)**2 + (2*zeta*rpico)**2)**(1/2)
zyl = []

for item in ZY:
  if item > 1.5 and item < 2:
    zyl.append(item)
```

A ideia é a mesma da sua: criar um novo array com os valores válidos. Porém, no seu código, você não tinha criado a variável `zyl` antes de entrar no loop, então dava um erro. Por isso, criei ela vazia no começo.

Ao invés de percorrer o vetor ZY com dois índices (i,j) é mais fácil fazer o loop iterando direto pelos próprios valores de ZY.